# Intellilock brakes signed dll hash value

Tags: license-key, net-reactor, intellilock

I want use Intellilock 1.8 for locking a Outlook2010 Add-in package. 
It includes among other Mocrosoft VSTO dlls my custom signed dll and the manifest file with security hash.
I provided project *.snk Key File when locking that dll but still receive an error when try to install the final package:

> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: File,
>   OutlookAddIn2010.dll, has a different computed hash than specified in
>   manifest.

The original Visual Studio Setup also automatically creates signed ClickOnce manifest. 
The main dll is mentioned in this section:

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="OutlookAddIn2010.dll" size="275968">
      <assemblyIdentity name="OutlookAddIn2010" version="2.7.0.0" publicKeyToken="DEDC24E24E6D7D88" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>Vg17KBReMnOV9emW0ddVuN7AaIU=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to apply IntelliLock signing before the main build.
The solution is the same as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942366/cannot-execute-custom-code-in-csproj-after-compile-but-before-build).

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Command="$(IntelliLockLocation) -project $(IntelliLockProject) -file &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)&quot; -targetfile &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)&quot;  -snkeypair &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)&quot; -snpassword *****" />
  </Target>
```